# How to implement social login with Node js

Tags: node.js, authentication

I have some app with authentication. How to implement authentication from different resources like Facebook and Google? I have the following schema

```
  const userSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Name is required'],
    unique: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    trim: true,
    required: [true, 'Email address is required'],
    validate: [validateEmail, 'Please fill a valid email address'],
    match: [/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/, 'Please fill a valid email address']
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Password is required']
  },
  authMethod: [{
    type: String,
    id: String,
    email: {
      required: [true, 'Email address is required']
    },
    name: String
  }],
  basket: {
    type: Array
  },
  selectedProducts: {
    type: Array
  },
  resetPasswordToken: String,
  resetPasswordExpire: Date,
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});
```

The problem is, that I have no idea how to handle user data from Facebook or Google. First of all when users registering via a standard form they entering the password which saves to DB. But when the same user logs via some of these services there no password. How should I write this data to DB? In general, I don't know how my schema should look like and how a should handle this various cases of user login

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look at [passportjs](http://www.passportjs.org/)

- [passport-facebook](http://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-facebook/)
- [passport-google](http://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-google-oauth/)